# Does docker need a linux image as a dependency to run embedded-jetty spring boot war file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, embedded-jetty, docker-image

I have an embedded-jetty based spring boot war file and I am able to run it in my windows OS with the below command and it works fine.

`java -jar my_app.war`

Am new to docker, I want to run my my_app.war in a docker container.

Now to create an image of my_app.war, do I first need to include a linux image dependency and then add openjdk8 image ?

or

I can directly create an image for my_app.war by using openjdk8 image dependency alone ?

Comment: show your dockerfile. how u create image

Comment: Factually, you want to run your application in docker. Whether that is a war in some kind of container or just a standalone spring boot application doesn't really matter does it? I would keep your life as easy as possible and deploy your app as documented: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Comment: @Gimby thanks for response. The page has good information on how to containerize the spring applications. 

My question is in my windows OS all I need is java to run my_app.jar, so when the image for my_app.jar is finally built and started as a container in docker engine. What basically happens ? Did docker download a small linux os, installed java init and then started my_app.war in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both ways.
Basically openjdk8 will also have some image dependency.
it will directly give you openjdk with dependency resolved in case of inux image you have to resolve those dependency.

reference: https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: Thanks for your response!
So how do I choose between openjdk8 approach and manual approach(resolving all image dependencies for my_app.war). Could you please let me know which is the right way ?

And If I go with the manual approach what are the possible challenges ?

Comment: well, it depends on use case if you want to run with specific linux image(Ex: fedora,centos,ubuntu) you should go with manual approach and for ease of use  go with prebuilt openjdk images.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into building from one of the images [here][1].

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
ADD ./path/to/war/my_app.war dir-in-container/my_app.war
CMD ["java", "-jar", "dir-in-container/my_app.war"]
```

This is from the top of my head, you might have to fiddle with it a little bit. Usually go for light images like Alpine, and as a general pointer, don't ADD or COPY your files in the base path of the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
Could you please tell me why do I need jetty image ? coz my_app.war has embedded-jetty container dependencies in the form of binaries, so all I need is java for running it.

Comment: You are right, no need for the jetty image. I usually go for ```FROM openjdk:8-alpine``` since it's lightweight but have a browse and see what works best for you. Sorry for the confusion, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you need to add openjdk image.

You can build image like this with open-jdk-8.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

ADD /build/libs/app.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try out this and will let you know if it works

Answer (score 0):

I use Tomcat image as basis for war deployments:

Here is Dockerfile you can try if your project runs with Java 11

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-jre11-slim

COPY target/libs/binsy.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xmx3168m -Xms3168m"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!
As already mentioned my_app.war just need java for running it and it has embedded-jetty binaries packaged in the war file itself. So why should I use the tomcat image ?